Name of a function whose difference between two points equals the "quasi" metric distance between the points?
I have a map $d:X \times X \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies:

$d(x,x)=0$

$d(x,y)=-d(y,x)$


Firstly, I don't know the name of such a structure, but I'll call it a quasi-metric until someone corrects me.
Question: Suppose there exists a function $f:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $d(x,y) = f(y)-f(x)$. Is there a standard name for such a function?

Incidentally, you can drop $d(x,x)=0$ because that follows from $d(x,y)=-d(y,x)$ when $y=x$. -- But you neither postulate that $d(x,y)=0\implies x=y$, nor do you have anything in the direction of tirangle inequality?

The positivity of a distance function looks essential to me. Why don't you define $d$ with an absolute value $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ instead of your second axiom $d(y,x)=-d(x,y)$ ?

@HagenvonEitzen, that is correct. I don't assume d(x,y)=0 nor triangle inequality.

@JeanMarie, I don't because that just doesn't apply to my circumstance. Essentially, d(x,y) measures more of an "ordering" than a distance.

The condition $d(x,y) = f(y)-f(x)$ means $d(x,y)+d(y,z)+d(x,z)=0$, which essentially enforces the triangle inequality (for $|d|$, that is).

@IvanNeretin, your last one should be $d(z,x)$

@user56834 I stand corrected. The conclusion, however, still persists.

@IvanNeretin, yes, but to be clear, it is d(x,y) that I care about, not it's absolute value.
